# servlet working fine for me(host) but in client

Tags: java, html, servlets

i am a beginner with only little basics.

**Aim:**
I am having a html(or jsp) page. when I click a button it should open google.com and yahoo.com in two separate tabs. it should work in the network when hostserver(mine) is ON.

**Programming part:**
I programmed the html page.... 
in servelet i used the following code

```
java.awt.Desktop.getDesktop().browse(java.net.URI.create(www.google.com));
java.awt.Desktop.getDesktop().browse(java.net.URI.create(www.yahoo.com));
```

**Result**:
Programme works 100% very well as expected in mine.. i.e host.
but not working in network client.
in client system: the html page is coming. servlet responding fine(i guess). after submitting, page routes to expected page also. only the above java.awt code part is not running.

someone help me. thanks in advance.

Comment: ? does client have proxy settings?

Comment: the method java.awt.Desktop.getDesktop().browse will open the given URL in the system's default web client. So if you have Chrome as your default browser it will use chrome. So it is not guaranteed to run on all machines.

Comment: Okay, let me see if I got that right. You have a servlet with a function so that, when triggered by a user, the server will open Google and Yahoo in its default browser. Is that the intended behaviour? Really?

Answer (score 1):

This will  **never** work because awt/swing are standalone.

So this will only at work server side but wont work in client side.